# Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysqli, undefined, mysql-real-escape-string

I try to insert array into my database. but before that I gt an error :

```
Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_escape_string()
```

my code as follow:

```
if(!empty($img_src)){

    $img_src = $db->mysqli_escape_string(serialize($img_src));

    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO photo_upload(`post_id`,`img_src`) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt2->bind_param('is', mysqli_insert_id($db),$img_src);
    $stmt2->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be `real_escape_string`,

```
$img_src = serialize($img_src);
$img_src = $db->real_escape_string($img_src);
```

*[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)*.

Comment: you are right but I got this Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: Yes, should be variable only. See my updated answer.

Comment: I got both error Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given 

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `$img_src` if you're using it with `bind_param`. You'll also have to save `mysqli_insert_id($db)` into a variable to use it in `bind_param` as all arguments after the first are passed by reference. Or simply use `$db->insert_id`...

```
if(!empty($img_src)){

    $img_src = serialize($img_src);

    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO photo_upload(`post_id`,`img_src`) VALUES (?,?)");
    if (!$stmt2) {
        throw new Exception($db->error, $db->errno);
    }
    $stmt2->bind_param('is', $db->insert_id, $img_src);
    if (!$stmt2->execute()) {
        throw new Exception($stmt2->error, $stmt2->errno);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: @user3346088 That's right. The return value of a function (like `mysqli_insert_id`) cannot be passed by reference but an object property like `$db->insert_id` can.

Comment: img_src contains array item, I seem doing it wrongly, everything is dumb into a row.. which i expect each array for one item.